# Reliably method to open xlsx to full size (wait until file is open)

Tags: python, winapi, xlsx, win32com

I am running a python script on both my laptop and home computer with:

```
os.startfile(r'C:\\A file.xlsx')
```

This works great, however I want it full size.

Any idea on how I can make it full size through python?

The following tends to work:

```
import win32gui, win32con, os, time

os.startfile('C:\\A File.xlsx')
time.sleep(10)  
hwnd = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
win32gui.ShowWindow(hwnd, win32con.SW_MAXIMIZE)
```

Without time.sleep, it does not go full size so time.sleep is needed.  I need a high time.sleep because of my slow laptop, however this means it runs slow on my home pc.

I use both Apache OpenOffice and microsoft Excel

Any idea how I can make an excel open full [size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1MPi.png) reliably without time.sleep?

Comment: win32api.ShellExecute can do this as can Popen although the latter requires the executable path

Comment: @AlexK. Can you show example of how this might be achieved?  I can't seem to find any documentation of this and solution above is slow and error prone

Answer (score 0):

The solution with win32com and Excel would be:

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
xl = Dispatch('Excel.Application')
xl.WindowState = -4137 # set this number meaning full size
xl.Visible = 1
xl.Workbooks.Open(r'C:\\A file.xlsx')
```

The excel is open on the full size of the screen. But no idea for Apache